# Nested dropdown list in web page not displaying

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have a web page, In the menu bar of this I have a button which dropdowns the list of components. There are few submenu components under these components. I am not able to get this. I want the main menu and the component and further submenu of these component. I tried the following code

```
<ul id="menu-top" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="dashboard.php" class="menu-top-active">DASHBOARD</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddlmenuItem" data-toggle="dropdown"> Categories <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddlmenuItem">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddlmenuItem">North,/ul>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="add-category.php">Add Category</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="manage-categories.php">Manage Categories</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddlmenuItem">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddlmenuItem">South/ul>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="add-language1.php">Add Language</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="manage-language1.php">Manage Language</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="manage-language1.php">Add Population</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
```

I want it to display like This
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rztQG.jpg)

Fiddle is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayc14z9s/1/)

Comment: Can you do a working snippet? If you are using bootstrap, maybe you made an error or loaded bootstrap incorrectly.

Comment: @Bootstrap it is correct Problem is with coding .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   

    <style>
        /* Remove default bullets */
        ul,
        #myUL {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        /* Remove margins and padding from the parent ul */
        #myUL {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        /* Style the caret/arrow */
        .caret {
            cursor: pointer;
            user-select: none;
            /* Prevent text selection */
        }

        /* Create the caret/arrow with a unicode, and style it */
        .caret::before {
            content: "\25B6";
            color: black;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 6px;
        }

        /* Rotate the caret/arrow icon when clicked on (using JavaScript) */
        .caret-down::before {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }

        /* Hide the nested list */
        .nested {
            display: none;
        }

        /* Show the nested list when the user clicks on the caret/arrow (with JavaScript) */
        .active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>


    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="myUL">
        <li><span class="caret">Beverages</span>
            <ul class="nested">
                <li>Water</li>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li><span class="caret">Tea</span>
                    <ul class="nested">
                        <li>Black Tea</li>
                        <li>White Tea</li>
                        <li><span class="caret">Green Tea</span>
                            <ul class="nested">
                                <li>Sencha</li>
                                <li>Gyokuro</li>
                                <li>Matcha</li>
                                <li>Pi Lo Chun</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <script>
        var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
            toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
                this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```